# Unable to delete folder with phantom sub-folders / files

Tags: hard-drive, folders

I had a `postgres` database folder which I had sent to the trash. However, I've been unable to empty the trash because it gives me the following error:

`The operation can’t be completed because the item “<item_name>” is in use.`

I'm fairly certain I had shut down the database before moving the folder. Nevertheless, normally, I'd be able to restart the computer and these sorts of errors would dissipate: but in this case the error persists.

I've also noted some slow-downs and, suspecting disk issues, have run disk utility, which now gives the following error:

```
Checking the object map.
error: (oid 0x4000000231b5a) om: btn: invalid o_cksum (0xdbe7569c81c16ed7)
Object map is invalid.
The volume /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely.
```

When exploring the un-deletable folder I noticed that there are some phantom sub-folders (or files without extensions) in the directory. I can't see these from the terminal if using `ls`, and the only reason I noticed them is because when using the `cd` command to drill-down into the directory I sometimes use the tab key to auto-suggest / auto-complete the next level of nested directory names: when doing so, a whole bunch of phantom folders appears.

I am unable to delete these folders using the usual `rm -r <dir>` type of approach..., which simply gives the `No such file or directory` error, so I'm not really sure what to try next.

Any ideas for how to forcefully remove the phantom folders / files and get the disk back to normal?

It is an APFS Container / fusion drive consisting of SSD and spinning platter disks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else coming across this issue. The solution entailed formatting the hard drive, after which disk utility was able to do its thing and the data could be restored.